# error in compile of plugin in stand alone gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear my friends,

I've downloaded the plugins from [this address](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e7a3fa0ce69f/plugins?at=default), but when i run `cmake..` i get this error

```
        root@vahid:~/plugin# cd build/
root@vahid:~/plugin/build# cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (gz_install_includes):
  Unknown CMake command "gz_install_includes".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

what is my wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2910/error-in-compile-of-plugin-in-stand-alone-gazebo/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The plugin directory in gazebo sources can not be compiled standalone. You must download the whole gazebo repository, and compile everything.

Alternatively, you can [install](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install) the gazebo deb which will install all the plugins.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlberSaber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7103/albersaber/) on 2018-11-01**:
the link is not working